# Universe inside atom in Hinduism (Sanatana dharma)

Tags: scripture, universe, cosmology, yoga-vashishtha

Sanatana dharma says that universe can exist inside atoms.

Yoga Vasistha, a scripture of Sanatana dharma, mentions across its body about the universe(s) inside atoms.

I am quoting a small example from it

> There are numberless worlds of creations, in earth, water and air and
> in everything under the sky, as if they are compressed or carved in
> the body of a huge block of stone.
>
> [[14, 70, 7, Yoga Vasistha]](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/yoga-vasistha-english/d/doc228767.html)

Are there other scriptures in Sanatana dharma that mention the same fact of atomic universes?

Comment: You are misinterpreting the meaning. It doesn't say inside atoms. "....as if" is a metaphor. Metaphors work only one way.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda I quoted an example only. Yoga Vasista do mention about universes inside atom.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda And if possible, please do comment for all your down-votes.